# Are there any non java view alternatives for spring MVC?

Tags: spring

Are there any non java view alternatives to thymeleaf and JSP for the spring MVC framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spring MVC you are not tied to any specific view layer. You could easily use JSP, Tiles, Freemarker, Velocity or Thymeleaf for creating views. It's just a matter of configuring the selected view renderer.

And of course Spring MVC does not limit you in any way as to what front-end JS framework you use. You can pick choose anything you like, including Angular that you mention.

[Here](https://github.com/joshlong/spring-doge/tree/master/spring-doge-web) is a sample Spring project from two Spring developer that uses Spring and Angular.

[Here](http://spring.io/blog/2014/05/12/springone2gx-2013-replay-spring-io-inside-and-out) you can checkout a series of tutorials that explains some of design of the new spring.io site, that is built using some cool JS stuff (among a heck of a lot of other cool stuff :)). More specifically [this](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/tree/65fffb1111b75ab5b7301e1ce281c038278a64b5/sagan-client) is where you can find the front-end code for the site.

Finally you might want to take a look at [JHipster](http://jhipster.github.io/) which is a Yeoman generator used to create a Spring + Angular JS project